# Find the splitting field of $x^4+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Find the splitting field of $x^4+4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

$x^4+4$ has, as roots,

$x = \sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}\cdot e^{in\pi/4}$, $n=0,1,2,3$

The splitting field is, then

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \pm e^{i\pi/4}, \pm e^{i3\pi/4}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, e^{i\pi/4}, e^{i3\pi/4})$$

But $e^{i3\pi/4} = (e^{i\pi/4})^3$, so we end up with

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, e^{i\pi/4})$$

Am I right?

I need to calculate the degree of this splitting field. I'm thinking about taking $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, e^{i\pi/4}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, e^{i\pi/4}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]$

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$

Now for the other one:

$$x = e^{i\pi/4} = \cos \pi/4 + i\sin \pi/4 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\implies$$

$$x^8 = e^{i2\pi} = \cos 2\pi + i\sin 2\pi = -1$$

So the polynomial that has $e^{i\pi/4}$ as root is $x^8+1$. I'm certain I can find a second degree polynomial with this root, so $x^8+1$ must be irreducible, but there are so many polynomials to divide. Is there a better way?

Also, am I on the right track?

Comment: Note that $x^4+4$ isn't irreducible - it is $(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2).$

Comment: Why do you think $\sqrt{2}$ is in your field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making things very complicated. Note that
$$\sqrt 2 e^{\pi i/4}=\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac i{\sqrt2}\right)
=1+i.$$
Similarly the other zeroes of $x^4+4$ are $1-i$, $-1+i$ and $-1-i$
(draw these on the Argand diagram!). It is plain that the splitting field
is $\Bbb Q(i)$. Indeed
$$x^4+4=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2).$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-$$x^4+4=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)=(x+1+i)(x+1-i)(x-1+i)(x+1-i)$$
The four roots are in $\mathbb Q(i)$ so the splitting field is $\mathbb Q(i)$.

Comment: How would you know that $x^4 + 4$ has the factorization $(x^2 + 2x + 2)((x^2 - 2x + 2)$?

Comment: @Junglemath:  It is a simple calculation. If you do not see this clearly then make a product of two trinomials of the second degree with indeterminate coefficients.

Comment: My point is that there has to be some clever insight that allows you to write this particular polynomial this way. I don't think this would work for $x^4 + A$, for a random $A$.

Comment: @Junglemath: You always have $x^4+A=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)$ where $a_1=\sqrt[4]{iA}=-a_2$,  and $a_3=\sqrt[4]{i^3A}=-a_4$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. From this try to see when you have a "good" factorization (clearly not always so you are right). Regards.

Comment: @Junglemath: 

As far as I know, there is no other than the calculation of the coefficients, but here a certain intuition helps. For the case of $A = 4$ it is very easy I think. Apparently it is the only case from factoring in four linear factors (not real almost all) that I have given you. Note that for $A = 1$ you have $(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)$ with irrational real coefficients.